# Programmatically configure EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AMI with some pre-installed software on it.  When I create a new instance I have to SSH into the machine and run some script depending on the server's use case.

For example:

```
ssh ubuntu@1.2.3.4 -i aws.pem  && ./type1.sh
ssh ubuntu@5.6.7.8 -i aws.pem  && ./type2.sh
```

Is there a way to automate this process?  I'm working with python.  I know I can use boto to stand the server up but I'm unsure of the best practices in regards to connecting to the server and running a script.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to automate. Isn't the script automating some process for you already?

Comment: @busybear Basically I want to automate the whole life cycle.  So I create an instance with boto and then "somehow" ssh into the machine and run the script.  I'm just curious as to how people are accomplishing the "somehow" part.

Comment: @busybear I guess I'm overthinking it.  I think I already have my solution.

Comment: Cool. Well paramiko is a Python package for SSH if that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of building your own python-based solution, you can simply use the ability to run code after the first boot of an EC2 instance, which AWS already provides.

When creating an EC2 instance you can provide some so called "user data", which can contain code which gets executed after the first boot of the instance. That is possible for all ways to create an EC2 instance, be it the management console, CLI, API, `boto3` or CloudFormation. The AWS documentation contains pretty extensive information how that works: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

If you create your EC2 instance using the `boto3` for example that would look like:

```python
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client("ec2")
ec2_client.run_instances(ImageId="ami-abcd1234",
                         InstanceType="m3.medium",
                         SubnetId="subnet-abcd1234",
                         SecurityGroupIds=["sg-abcd1234"],
                         UserData="/home/ubuntu/type1.sh"
)
```